# PHPExcel: how to read values from cells which the contents come from cells in other sheets

Tags: php, excel, laravel, phpexcel

I have spent the last days trying to solve this issue. I have a spreadsheet with a couple tabs (sheets). The last tab has the values input in all other tabs. Those values are populated automatically by using formulas like:

```
=$'otherSheetName'.A1
```

If I leave `calculateFormulas = true` those values are read as null. 
If I set `calculateFormulas = false` the values are read as the literal formula.

I was firstly using LaravelExcel but I gave up from finding a solution for that, so I moved to PHPExcel. Solutions for Laravel Excel will be appreciated too though.

Thanks

Update:
How I am reading values in PHPExcel:

```
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($file->getRealPath());
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly("MySheet");
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($file->getRealPath()); 
$rows = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);
```

Then, I iterate over the array $rows and extract the values that I want.

Comment: How are you trying to read the values in PHPExcel? Are you using getCalculatedValue()?

Comment: And the Excel formula should be like `='otherSheetName'!A1` with the sheetname in single quotes, and a `!` separating the sheetname from the cell address

Comment: @MarkBaker I updated my post. Check there how I am reading the values. Regarding the formula, it looks exactly as I put there - and it works fine. I didn't create it by the way.

Comment: Well your update answers some of the question...... if you read a singe sheet only (`$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly("MySheet");`), then PHPExcel cannot possibly ever figure out the values from cells in other sheets

Comment: @MarkBaker you're right! That's exactly the problem. But now I need to read every sheet until I get to the one I need (I am only interested in one). Do you know how to access a sheet directly without having to iterate over the whole spreadsheet? And please, submit an answer so I can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load all the dependency sheets that are used in those formulae, though you don't necessarily need to load every worksheet, but can pass a list of sheet names to load as an array

```
$objReader->setLoadSheetsOnly(["MySheet", "OtherSheet1", "OtherSheet2"]);
```

You don't need to iterate over any other worksheets, but can set the active worksheet to whichever sheet you want

```
$objReader->setActiveSheetIndexByName("MySheet");
```

and then any calls to the active sheet (`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->...`) to access cells will be a reference to that worksheet.

Comment: Thank you very much! It hits the nail on the head!

Comment: One last question, do you know the equivalent of this "setActiveSheetIndexByName" method in Laravel Excel?

Comment: @Leandro - I don't know, but as the Maatwebsite wrapper uses PHPExcel, and allows access to PHPExcel methods, then it should be possible